# Fix Process ID For Python Script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I want to setup my python script to always use a fixed process id. So that every time I want to kill it I don't have to do a ps aux for it. Please Help.

I am using Ubuntu & CentOS.

Ubuntu is my testing system
CentOS is my server

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that?

Comment: I agree with @Tichodroma - I also doubt it's possible. Is anything wrong with the normal idiom of a process writing its PID to a <processname>.pid file and using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write a small script for deleting your process:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Kill my python process called myPython
kill `ps -A | grep myPython | nawk '{ print $1}'`
# Or
kill `ps -U myname | grep myPython | nawk '{ print $1}'`
```

And then you can just run the script to kill the process...

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible, Posix process ids are guaranteed to be random (e.g. `OpenSSL` uses the process id to seed it's random number generator). Only thing you can do, is writing the process id into a file and killing the process based on the written process id.

```
kill `cat x.pid`
```

Comment: What do you mean, guaranteed to be random? All Linux versions I've ever used just have a counter it keeps track of, and just uses the next available pid as the new pid.  Run ps | grep ps a few times and you'll see.

Comment: That's true but you can't tell which id your process will get.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something you can do, with python or any other process.

The process id is assigned by the Linux kernel, and there are guarantees as to the uniqueness of the id.

Moreover, if your process is used a child process of another, it's process id lives on in the kernel process table until the parent process has acknowledged that it has read the exit status. That means you cannot simply re-use the process id at a later time, it may still be reserved in the process table.

I'm sure you can devise a creative kill command that'll catch your process every time:

```
kill `ps -fC python2.7 | grep yourscriptname.py`
```

or similar.